# How to scan name and surname separated with space with scanf function in C without using loop and save it in one variable?

Tags: c, scanf

I tried using `%[]` but VSC immediately paint the `%` red and report an error.

[image]

Comment: `scanf("%s %s", name, surname)`? Or do you mean store them into a single variable? It would help if you gave a complete [mre] as well as the expected result vs actual result. Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: A decent rule is: if you're just starting out with `scanf`, don't use `%[]`.  Scanf's virtue is that it is nice and simple, but `%[]` is not simple.  Unless the name and surname will contain a space, you don't need `%[]`.  If you're doing something complicated enough that you actually do need `%[]`, it means (IMO) that it's time to learn [how to use something better than `scanf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scanf()` to read a string with embedded spaces this way:

```
char fullname[100];

if (scanf("%99[^\n]", fullname) == 1) {
    printf("The full name is: %s\n", fullname);
} else {
    // either end of file was reached, scanf returned EOF
    // or no character was typed before the newline
    printf("input error\n");
}
// read and discard the rest of the line
scanf("%*[^\n]");  // discard the remaining characters if any
scanf("%*1[\n]");  // discard the newline if any
```

The reason Visual Studio Code shows an error is the syntax `%[]` is invalid. You cannot specify an empty set. The `]` just after the `%[` is interpreted as a `]` character and there must be another `]` to close the set as in `%[]]`.

`scanf()` is full of quirks and pitfalls: it seems easier and safer to use `fgets()` or `getline()` to read a line of input and then perform explicit clean up of the string read from the user, such as removing the initial and trailing whitespace, which requires a loop in most cases.

Comment: VSC shows an error in every syntax i tried including %[...]. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the VSC colorizer. It should not prevent compilation.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, i concluded that program works fine and VSC painted '%' red for no reason. Thanks for your answers, they were useful.